# Kotlin DSL for collections

Tags: kotlin, dsl

This is a simple data structure `House` which contains a (nullable) list of `Person`  :

```
data class Person(val name: String,
                  val militaryYear: Int? = null,
                  val firstPregnantYear: Int? = null)
data class House(val persons: List<Person>?)
```

`Person` maybe male or female. Male has `militaryYear` value , Female has `firstPregnantYear` value.

I want to write a DSL to build the `House` object , like this :

```
val house = house {
  person("John") {
    militaryYear = 2003
  }
  person("Anne") {
    firstPregnantYear = 2010
  }
}
```

This is what I have done :

```
data class Person(val name: String,
                  val militaryYear: Int? = null,
                  val firstPregnantYear: Int? = null) {

  class Builder(private val name: String) {
    var militaryYear : Int? = null
    var firstPregnantYear : Int? = null
    fun build(): Person = Person(name, militaryYear, firstPregnantYear)
  }
}
fun person(name: String , block: Person.Builder.() -> Unit) = Person.Builder(name).apply(block).build()



data class House(val persons: List<Person>?) {
  class Builder {
    var persons = mutableListOf<Person>()

    fun person(name: String , block: Person.Builder.() -> Unit) {
      persons.add(Person.Builder(name).apply(block).build())
    }

    fun build(): House = House(persons = persons.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() })
  }
}
```

It seems works , but it doesn't forbid both `militaryYear` & `firstPregnantYear` , for example :

```
val house = house {
  person("John") {
    militaryYear = 2003
  }
  person("Anne") {
    firstPregnantYear = 2010
  }
  person("Alien") {
    militaryYear = 2005
    firstPregnantYear = 2009
  }
}
println(house)
```

The result :

```
House(persons=[
Person(name=John, militaryYear=2003, firstPregnantYear=null)
, Person(name=Anne, militaryYear=null, firstPregnantYear=2010)
, Person(name=Alien, militaryYear=2005, firstPregnantYear=2009)
])
```

The `Alien` has `militaryYear` & `firstPregnantYear` , which is incorrect.

So , I add another `MaleBuilder` and `FemaleBuilder` :

```
  class MaleBuilder(private val name: String) {
    var militaryYear = 0
    fun build(): Person = Person(name, militaryYear, null)
  }

  class FemaleBuilder(private val name: String) {
    var firstPregnantYear = 0
    fun build() : Person = Person(name , null , firstPregnantYear)
  }

fun male(name: String , block: Person.MaleBuilder.() -> Unit) = Person.MaleBuilder(name).apply(block).build()
fun female(name: String , block: Person.FemaleBuilder.() -> Unit) = Person.FemaleBuilder(name).apply(block).build()
```

And the DSL becomes :

```
val house = house {
  male("John") {
    militaryYear = 2003
  }
  female("Anne") {
    firstPregnantYear = 2010
  }
}
println(house)
```

OK , here is the problem , `male("John")` and `female("Anne")` are not inserted into `persons` . It outputs :

```
House(persons=null)
```

I think the problem comes from House's person() function :

```
fun person(name: String , block: Person.Builder.() -> Unit) {
  persons.add(Person.Builder(name).apply(block).build())
}
```

The defined receiver is `Person.Builder` , but it is `MaleBuilder` and `FemaleBuilder` in the code.

How to solve this problem ?

Full code : https://pastebin.com/1Q6D8rzx

------- updated -------

It can be solved by introducing `House.Builder.male()` and `House.Builder.female()` functions :

```
fun male(name: String , block: Person.MaleBuilder.() -> Unit) {
  persons.add(Person.MaleBuilder(name).apply(block).build())
}

fun female(name: String , block: Person.FemaleBuilder.() -> Unit) {
  persons.add(Person.FemaleBuilder(name).apply(block).build())
}
```

But I think it is not a good solution.  In real world example , there maybe a lot of properties , and a lot of restrictions. Is there a way to use one function to receive it ?

Comment: Look at the hints in your IDE. The top-level person() function is useless. You never call it. What you call is the person() function of the House.Builder class. That's the function that creates a person and adds it to the list of persons of the house. So the top-level male and female functions shouldn't exist either. They should be methods of the House.Builder class, that work similarly as the person() methord of the Builder.

Comment: Thanks , the top-level person() is truly useless. But I don't like `House.Builder.male()` , `House.Builder.female()` methods . I use male and female just for explanation. In real world example , there maybe a lot of properties , and a lot of restrictions. Is there a way to use one function to receive it ?

Comment: If you use only one function, it can have only one type of Builder as argument, but you want to build two different kinds of persons. You already tried only one function, and you didn't like it either, so...